# how to know apache POI reading excel all data using gwt java

Tags: java, excel, gwt, apache-poi

I am reading excel file using Apache POI in gwt using java. I have one excel file with 15000 records and four columns Count, Name, Mob No and EmailID. I am uploading excel file in blobstore GAE then I am reading that excel file.  I am just checking with logger all data is reading or not. when I deployed and test then only last 266 rows are reading and displayed in logger. Why? how to read all data from excel. my code is:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(newBlobstoreInputStream(blobkey));
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
        // For each row, iterate through each columns 
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); 
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) { 
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                   logger.log(Level.SEVERE,cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                    break; 
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:                    
                   logger.log(Level.SEVERE,cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                   break; 
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: 
                   logger.log(Level.SEVERE,cell.getBooleanCellValue() +"\t");
                    break;
                default : 
                }
            } 
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

how shall i read all data from start to end? 
any help Thanks in advance

And One more is when i change XSSFWorkbook and XSSFSheet instead of HSSFWorkbook and HSSFSheet to read Xlsx excel then its throw Exception : org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents.  how can i fix this

Any help 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the exception you are getting, .xls files are read by HSSFWorkbook & HSSFSheet whereas .xlsx are read by XSSFWorkbook & XSSFSheet.
You can use the Factory class to get the appropriate Workbook if you are goin to handle both .xls & .xlsx format.

Comment: Thanks Rahul what is factory class how can i use could you explain me.

Comment: You can refer https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html